# Terminal only opens matlab and does NOT execute any commands

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

Recently I have tried to edit my .bash_profile and add a path which enables matlab to be opened when called directly from the terminal. In the .bash_profile I have also added a line:

```
/usr/local/Applications/MATLAB_R2015a_node.app/bin/matlab
```

I saved that and tried opening the terminal. Since then, my terminal automatically only opens matlab and does not allow me to execute any commands or open a bash_profile to delete/change that.

This is how my terminal looks like when opened:

[image]

I have tried many things suggested from this forum but I am unable to do anything.   Does anyone know a way to solve this? Also, how can I find a hidden bash_profile when terminal does not execute any commands? I have the OS X El Capitan (version 10.11.6).

One more thing, while matlab is open I can type in the terminal but it does not execute the commands, once I close the matlab I cannot anymore type in the terminal. Once matlab closed, in the terminal appears:

> Saving session... ...process completed

The location of the matlab file is as displayed in this photo:

[image: photo]

Comment: Show us a terminal window with the output for the current working directory, and a listing of the files, so we know the file is actually where you believe it is.  The error you recieved is really specific, the file does not exist, in the location the script is pointing to.

Comment: What happens if you press the Control key and the c key? Does the prompt return?

Comment: When I press control + c keys in the terminal, matlab reacts by starting a new line (equal to pressing enter) and nothing happens in the terminal.

Comment: @Ramhound I have posted a printscreen of file location, and the only output of the terminal is the one I have posted in the beginning of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.bash_profile` is located in `~/`, on macOS, this is `/Users/yourusername/`.

To open this hidden file in TextEdit, in the file open dialogue, navigate to your home folder and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> to show hidden files.